# Why doesn't decrementation work here the way it should?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, iteration

I am pretty sure I've made a silly mistake, but I cannot seem to find it for quite some time.

I (successfully) load some images, convert them to grayscale and thresh to b&w. Then I wanted to make a method that evaluates each row of pixels by measuring its avg color value (0…255) and give me the row number of the first one that is below a certain threshold. It works, but expanding the method to do the same thing from the bottom does not. Here's how it looks:

```
t_thresh_hor = 210.0

def core_text_loc(image):
    height, width = image.shape
    height = height - 1   # to adjust for starting with 0
    width = width - 1     # to adjust for starting with 0
    top_trim = 0
    bot_trim = height

    i = 0
    while i < height and top_trim == 0:
        row = image[i, 0:-1]
        i = i + 1
        if numpy.mean(row) < t_thresh_hor:
            top_trim = i
    # here it stops working
    i = height
    while i > 0 and bot_trim == height:
        row = image[height, 0:-1]
        if numpy.mean(row) < t_thresh_hor:
            bot_trim = i
        i = i - 1

    return(top_trim, bot_trim)
```

I know the threshold is correct (works when I manually access a specific line), but bot_trim always returns the height of the picture, meaning it stopped at the first iteration (?).
What have I done wrong?

EDIT:
**Sample case:** I am testing it on two pictures:
first one is 4724x3177, and the output is:
    top_trim: 1216 (correct)
    bot_trim: 4723 (should be ≈ 4400)
second one4705 3177
    top_trim: 315 (correct)
    bot_trim: 4704 (should be ≈ 4400)

Comment: What is the expected output? Please provide a sample case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
row = image[height, 0:-1]
```

You always read from the last row, not the `i`th row as you probably intended. Try changing `height` to `i`.

Answer (score 3):

In the second while loop, you used

```
row = image[height, 0:-1]
```

Whereas it should be

```
row = image[i, 0:-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
row = image[height, 0:-1]
```

to

```
row = image[i, 0:-1]
```